# Redux: addToCart function is only updating quantity and not adding the product to cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to Redux so finding it hard to troubleshoot where the issues are in my code especially since I have no errors.

Whenever I add a product to the cart my state is updated however it only updates the quantity of the cart and does not actually add the product to the cart.

Below is a screenshot of my Redux Tools and the relevant code snippets.
[image]

Card.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';


import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Card, Avatar, Button, Modal } from 'antd';
import { EditOutlined, EllipsisOutlined, PlusCircleTwoTone, SettingOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {addToCart}  from '../Redux/Shopping/ShoppingActions'



const { Meta } = Card;



function Cardo(props) {
    const {addToCart} = props;


    //Setting variables up to use for useState so to manage state of modal
    //Default state is false so not to be visible
    const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);

    const showModal = () => {
        setIsModalVisible(true);
    };

    const handleOk = () => {
        setIsModalVisible(false);
    };

    const handleCancel = () => {
        setIsModalVisible(false);
    };

    //^^^All the const's above will be called below within the card or modal to manage the state of the modal



    return (
        <div className="card">
            <Card
                style={{ width: "340px", textAlign: 'center' }}
                cover={<img className="card-cover" src={props.image}/>}
                actions={[
                    // <SettingOutlined key="setting" />,
                    // <EditOutlined onClick={showModal} key="edit" />,
                    <EllipsisOutlined onClick={showModal} key="ellipsis" />,
                ]}
            >
                <Meta
                    avatar={<Button className="card-button" onClick={() => addToCart(props.id)} type="primary" shape="circle"><PlusCircleTwoTone /></Button>}
                    title={props.header}
                    description={props.price}
                />
            </Card>
            <Modal title={props.header} visible={isModalVisible} onOk={handleOk} onCancel={handleCancel}>
                <p>{props.description}</p>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        addToCart: (id) => dispatch(addToCart(id)),
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Cardo)
```

ShoppingReducer.js

```
import * as actionTypes from './ShoppingTypes';
import data from '../../Data/MenuData';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    products: data,//(id, title, description, price, img)
    cart: [], //(id, title, description, price, img, qty)
    currentItem: null,
}

//reducer is just function that takes in state and action - action is part that gets dispatched which contains a type
const shopReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case actionTypes.ADD_TO_CART:
            //get items data from products array
            const item = state.products.find((product) => product.id === action.payload.id);
            //we need to check if item is in cart already
            const inCart = state.cart.find((item) => item.id === action.payload.id ? true : false);
            return{
                //we spread the state first so not to lose current or all the products
                ...state,
                //inCart we check if it is in cart and that return true - if so map through cart and find that id
                cart: inCart ? state.cart.map((item) =>
                     item.id === action.payload.id 
                     //Then spread all of data inside and change quantity if needed
                        ? {...item, qty: item.qty + 1} : item
                        ) //if not in cart then spread the array and add the item and quantity to state of cart 
                        : [...state.cart, { ...item, qty: 1}],
            };
        case actionTypes.REMOVE_FROM_CART:
            return{
                ...state,
                //this filters through array and deletes item we want to remove
                cart: state.cart.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.id)
            };
        case actionTypes.ADJUST_QTY:
            return{
                ...state,
                //if i find id in cart I want to recreate object by spreading current item and setting qty set to original qty - else return item
                cart: state.cart.map((item) => item.id === action.payload.id ? {...item, qty: action.payload.qty} : item)
            };
        case actionTypes.LOAD_CURRENT_ITEM:
            return{
                ...state,
                currentItem: action.payload,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }

}

export default shopReducer;
```

MenuData.js (which holds the data that is stored in products)

```
const data = [

    {
        id: 1,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Meat Dumplings",
        price: 4.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Veggie Dumplings",
        price: 3.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Duck Spring Rolls",
        price: 4.29,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Veggie Spring Rolls",
        price: 3.79,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Green Thai Curry",
        price: 9.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Red Thai Curry",
        price: 9.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Pad Thai",
        price: 12.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Japanese Curry",
        price: 10.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Spicy Sichuan Tofu Noodles",
        price: 8.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Tonkotsu Ramen",
        price: 12.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Spicy Miso Noodles",
        price: 7.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Oyaka Don",
        price: 8.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Matcha Brownies",
        price: 4.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Salted Caramel Brownies",
        price: 3.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 15,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Jasmine Rice",
        price: 2.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 16,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Sticky Japanese Rice",
        price: 3.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 17,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Basmati Rice",
        price: 1.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 18,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Egg Fried Rice",
        price: 3.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....' 
    },
]

export default data;
```

MyMenu.js (where the card is mapped)

```
import { Col, Row } from 'antd';
import React from 'react'
import Cardo from './Card';
import data from '../Data/MenuData';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import shopReducer from '../Redux/Shopping/ShoppingReducer';
import ReduxCardo from './ReduxRenderedCard';


const cardCreator = (product) => {
    return(
        <Cardo
            key={product.id}
            image={product.image}
            header={product.header}
            price={product.price}
            description={product.description}

        />
    )
}



function MyMenu({ products }) {
    return (
        <div className="menu">
            <h1 className="menu-header" >Starters</h1>
            <Row className="menu-row" gutter={{xs: 32, sm: 24, md: 16, lg: 8}}>
                {/* <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator1)};
                </Col> */}
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[0]}   
                </Col>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[1]}   
                </Col>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[2]}   
                </Col>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[3]}   
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <h1 className="menu-header">Mains</h1>
            <Row className="menu-row" gutter={{xs: 32, sm: 24, md: 16, lg: 8}}>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[4]}   
                </Col>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[5]}   
                </Col>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[6]}   
                </Col>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[7]}   
                </Col>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[8]}   
                </Col>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[9]}   
                </Col>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[10]}   
                </Col>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[11]}   
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <h1 className="menu-header">Rice</h1>
            <Row className="menu-row" gutter={{xs: 32, sm: 24, md: 16, lg: 8}}>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[14]}   
                </Col>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[15]}   
                </Col>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[16]}   
                </Col>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[17]}   
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <h1 className="menu-header">Desserts</h1>
            <Row className="menu-row" gutter={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[12]}
                </Col>
                <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                    {products.map(cardCreator)[13]}
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        products: state.shop.products,
    };

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyMenu);
```

ShoppingActions.js

```
import * as actionTypes from './ShoppingTypes';

export const addToCart = (itemID) => {
    return{
        type: actionTypes.ADD_TO_CART,
        payload: {
            id: itemID
        },
    };
};

export const removeFromCart = (itemID) => {
    return{
        type: actionTypes.REMOVE_FROM_CART,
        payload: {
            id: itemID
        },
    };
};

export const adjutQty = (itemID, value) => {
    return{
        type: actionTypes.ADJUST_QTY,
        payload: {
            id: itemID,
            qty: value,
        },
    };
};

export const loadCurrentItem = (item) => {
    return{
        type: actionTypes.LOAD_CURRENT_ITEM,
        payload: item,
    };
};
```

Comment: I [tested your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-waterfall-9mhdo?file=/src/store/slice.ts) and it works fine for me.  What you are seeing would be the expected behavior if your reducer cannot find an `item` in the `state.products` array that matches the `action.payload.id`.   So figure out why you are not finding a match.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Linda, when you say works fine for you do you mean that when you replicate it does actually add a product to the basket? I will follow what you've said and see if I can find where the issue lies

Comment: Sorry didn't realise you'd made a code sandbox just seen that now - It does look like you've added alot of new code that is alot more complex than my level of understanding of redux - is that why it works now because of all the additional code or did you mean my original code works fine on its own when replicated?

Comment: Are you sure that product with passed id exists in your products array? Can you console.log action.payload.id in reducer and additionally  show how products array in your state looks like?

Comment: When I console.log action.payload.id it comes back with undefined - I will update the post now so it shows the products array thanks!

Comment: ok, so the reducer looks fine to me, it is just not getting the id, the problem can be in yours addToCart action creator or id prop in Cardo Component.

Comment: I have been playing around with the Cardo Component al ot today to try and solve this but to no avail, I just edited the post and uploaded MyMenu.js snippet of code to the post also. In there I map data to the card so maybe my issues lies within that.

Comment: @MicSt the CodeSandbox that I posted earlier is basically a react/redux template that I copy and pasted your reducer and component into.  I see you’ve updated your post with more code so I will play with that but oh my gosh you do not understand mapping!  products.map(cardCreator)[0] etc is very silly.

Comment: The reason I was mapping it like that was because before I started implementing redux I just wanted to have the different products for different sections of menu and so just picked from each part of the array and that was simples solution  - if you have a suggestion for a much better way please do tell!

Comment: Move the `Col` inside the `cardCreator`.  Then to render the first 4 products just do `{products.slice(0,4).map(cardCreator)}`.  Next section is `{products.slice(4,12).map(cardCreator)}`, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to play with my CodeSandbox but it keeps freezing.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you've used some es6 functions wrong way in some places, and there are some mistakes on your code.

```
state.cart.find((item) => item.id === action.payload.id ? true : false);
```

This line will return a Cart object instead of boolean variable, anyways it could work in your case.

The main problem could from the same variable name in a same scope. Try to chance the map loop variable name to be difference like below.

```
            return{
                //we spread the state first so not to lose current or all the products
                ...state,
                //inCart we check if it is in cart and that return true - if so map through cart and find that id
                cart: inCart ? state.cart.map((it) =>
                     it.id === action.payload.id 
                     //Then spread all of data inside and change quantity if needed
                        ? {...item, qty: item.qty + 1} : item
                        ) //if not in cart then spread the array and add the item and quantity to state of cart 
                        : [...state.cart, { ...item, qty: 1}],
            };
```

Not sure, this is right answer, I hope this answer helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this, I think I understand your train of thought, however your solution did not fix the issue.