# Mapping products connected through Redux but they do not show?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, array.prototype.map

I am following this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNs_7avLIJ4) if you skip to 26 minutes it is the part I am following to render products connected through redux by mapping them.

I have no errors and my code is the same as the tutorial, I was originally rendering my products onto cards through props however I am trying to implement structure same as this tutorial because previously When I had followed the tutorial and applied it to my existing project I could not get redux to actually add products to my cart so am just trying to do it the way tutorial shows to see if this solves the issue... see post of my old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67130114/redux-addtocart-function-is-only-updating-quantity-and-not-adding-the-product-t?noredirect=1#comment118684416_67130114).

When I console.log(prod) it shows the products and all their data displaying so I do not know why it doesn't render them.

Code below:
MyMenu.js

```
import { Col, Row } from 'antd';
import React from 'react'
import Cardo from './Card';
import data from '../Data/MenuData';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import shopReducer from '../Redux/Shopping/ShoppingReducer';
import ReduxCardo from './ReduxRenderedCard';


// const cardCreator = (props) => {
//     return(
//         <Col span={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
//             <Cardo
//             key={props.id}
//             image={props.image}
//             header={props.header}
//             price={props.price}
//             description={props.description}

//             />
//         </Col>
        
//     )
// }



function MyMenu({ products }) {
    return (
        <div className="menu">
            <h1 className="menu-header" >Starters</h1>
            <hr className="menu-divider"/>
            <Row className="menu-row" gutter={{xs: 32, sm: 24, md: 16, lg: 8}}>
                {/* {products.slice(0,4).map(cardCreator)} */}
                {products.map((prod) => {
                    <ReduxCardo key={prod.id} productData={prod} />
                    console.log(prod);
                })}
                
            </Row>
            <h1 className="menu-header">Mains</h1>
            <hr className="menu-divider"/>
            <Row className="menu-row" gutter={{xs: 32, sm: 24, md: 16, lg: 8}}>
                {/* {products.slice(4, 12).map(cardCreator)} */}
         
            </Row>
            <h1 className="menu-header">Rice</h1>
            <hr className="menu-divider"/>
            <Row className="menu-row" gutter={{xs: 32, sm: 24, md: 16, lg: 8}}>
                {/* {products.slice(12,14).map(cardCreator)} */}
              
            </Row>
            <h1 className="menu-header">Desserts</h1>
            <hr className="menu-divider"/>
            <Row className="menu-row" gutter={{xs: 24, sm: 12, md: 8, lg: 6}}>
                {/* {products.slice(14,18).map(cardCreator)} */}
            </Row>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        products: state.shop.products,
    };

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyMenu);
```

ReduxRenderedCard.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';


import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Card, Avatar, Button, Modal } from 'antd';
import { EditOutlined, EllipsisOutlined, PlusCircleTwoTone, SettingOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {addToCart}  from '../Redux/Shopping/ShoppingActions'



const { Meta } = Card;



function ReduxCardo({productData, addToCart}) {

    //Setting variables up to use for useState so to manage state of modal
    //Default state is false so not to be visible
    const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);

    const showModal = () => {
        setIsModalVisible(true);
    };

    const handleOk = () => {
        setIsModalVisible(false);
    };

    const handleCancel = () => {
        setIsModalVisible(false);
    };

    //^^^All the const's above will be called below within the card or modal to manage the state of the modal



    return (
        <div className="card">
            <Card
                style={{ width: "340px", textAlign: 'center' }}
                cover={<img className="card-cover" src={productData.image}/>}
                actions={[
                    // <SettingOutlined key="setting" />,
                    // <EditOutlined onClick={showModal} key="edit" />,
                    <EllipsisOutlined onClick={showModal} key="ellipsis" />,
                ]}
            >
                <Meta
                    avatar={<Button className="card-button" onClick={() => addToCart(productData.id)} type="primary" shape="circle"><PlusCircleTwoTone /></Button>}
                    title={productData.header}
                    description={productData.price}
                />
            </Card>
            <Modal title={productData.header} visible={isModalVisible} onOk={handleOk} onCancel={handleCancel}>
                <p>{productData.description}</p>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        addToCart: (id) => dispatch(addToCart(id)),
    }
}



export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ReduxCardo);
```

Reducer code and data file below.

ShoppingReducer.js

```
import * as actionTypes from './ShoppingTypes';
import data from '../../Data/MenuData';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    products: data,//(id, title, description, price, img)
    cart: [], //(id, title, description, price, img, qty)
    currentItem: null,
}

//reducer is just function that takes in state and action - action is part that gets dispatched which contains a type
const shopReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    
    switch(action.type){
        case actionTypes.ADD_TO_CART:
            //get items data from products array
            const item = state.products.find((product) => product.id === action.payload.id);
            //we need to check if item is in cart already
            const inCart = state.cart.find((item) => item.id === action.payload.id ? true : false);
            // console.log(action.payload.id)
            return{
                //we spread the state first so not to lose current or all the products
                ...state,
                //inCart we check if it is in cart and that return true - if so map through cart and find that id
                cart: inCart ? state.cart.map((item) =>
                     item.id === action.payload.id 
                     //Then spread all of data inside and change quantity if needed
                        ? {...item, qty: item.qty + 1} : item
                        ) //if not in cart then spread the array and add the item and quantity to state of cart 
                        : [...state.cart, { ...item, qty: 1}],
            };
        case actionTypes.REMOVE_FROM_CART:
            return{
                ...state,
                //this filters through array and deletes item we want to remove
                cart: state.cart.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.id)
            };
        case actionTypes.ADJUST_QTY:
            return{
                ...state,
                //if i find id in cart I want to recreate object by spreading current item and setting qty set to original qty - else return item
                cart: state.cart.map((item) => item.id === action.payload.id ? {...item, qty: action.payload.qty} : item)
            };
        case actionTypes.LOAD_CURRENT_ITEM:
            return{
                ...state,
                currentItem: action.payload,
            };
            
        default:
            return state;
    }

}

export default shopReducer;
```

MenuData.js

```
const data = [

    {
        id: 1,
        image: 'https://d3lp4xedbqa8a5.cloudfront.net/s3/digital-cougar-assets/food/2014/11/28/WomansDayBR109894/steamed-beef-dumplings.jpg?width=600&height=315&quality=75&mode=crop',
        header: "Meat Dumplings",
        price: 4.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        image: 'https://pixel.parall.ax/parallax-agency/image/upload/w_560,h_575,c_fill/expose/cauldron-2018/images/49265d45f7_2018-12-19-12-21-27_1600_1067.jpg',
        header: "Veggie Dumplings",
        price: 3.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Duck Spring Rolls",
        price: 4.29,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Veggie Spring Rolls",
        price: 3.79,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Green Thai Curry",
        price: 9.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Red Thai Curry",
        price: 9.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Pad Thai",
        price: 12.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Japanese Curry",
        price: 10.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Spicy Sichuan Tofu Noodles",
        price: 8.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Tonkotsu Ramen",
        price: 12.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Spicy Miso Noodles",
        price: 7.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Oyaka Don",
        price: 8.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Matcha Brownies",
        price: 4.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Salted Caramel Brownies",
        price: 3.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 15,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Jasmine Rice",
        price: 2.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 16,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Sticky Japanese Rice",
        price: 3.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 17,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Basmati Rice",
        price: 1.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....'
    },
    {
        id: 18,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/699953/pexels-photo-699953.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        header: "Egg Fried Rice",
        price: 3.99,
        // amount: 1,
        description: 'Some Description here....' 
    },
]

export default data;
```

Comment: No errors while render? You sure, `products` props in `MyMenu` is not empty?

Comment: I dont think its empty because previously I was mapping products by doing {products.slice(4, 12).map(cardCreator)} and it displayed the products fine.